# I need help identifying what this block of code is in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code is located immediately after the #imports and before the @interface.

I know this is a very simple/stupid question. But I just want the correct term/name to describe this.

Thanks in advance.

```
static PHCVODCatalogDownloadState PHCVODCatalogDownloadStateFromString(NSString *stateString)
{
    if ([stateString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"downloaded"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        return PHCVODCatalogDownloadStateDownloaded;
    }
    else if ([stateString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"updating"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        return PHCVODCatalogDownloadStateUpdating;
    }
    else if ([stateString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"pending"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        return PHCVODCatalogDownloadStatePending;
    }
    else
    {
        return PHCVODCatalogDownloadStateUnknown;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a C function. Only callable from this source file because it's static.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an Objective-C "helper function", user-defined elsewhere, as a subclass of NSString. When called, it sends a message to compare the contents of stateString with one of 4 possible states (including "unknown") and returning an enumeration of the state.

Comment: also its a static function so it applie what others have answered as well which is "It's a C-function with static scope. This means only code in the .m file can access this function."

Answer (score 1):

It's a C-function with `static` scope. This means only code in the .m file can access this function.

Answer (score 1):

It is a C function. This code is using only .m file.